# How To get the user input text for wxSpellCheckerDialog

Tags: python, wxpython, spell-checking

I am new to the Python and I had struggled on how to pass the user input to the wxSpellCheckerDialog class.

Based on the sample code that I found, the author had mentioned to have a code such as below:
    This is most useful when the text to be checked is in the form of
    a character array, as it will be modified in place as the user
    interacts with the dialog.  For checking strings, the final result
    will need to be obtained from the SpellChecker object:

```
    >>> dlg = wxSpellCheckerDialog(None,-1,"")
    >>> chkr = SpellChecker("en_AU",text)
    >>> dlg.SetSpellChecker(chkr)
    >>> dlg.ShowModal()
    >>> text = dlg.GetSpellChecker().get_text()
```

However, I had placed in my Python code, it is still not working correctly.

Could I have the any help on how to assign the user input sentence for wxSpellCheckerDialog?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't obvious is it?

```
import wx
from enchant.checker import SpellChecker
from enchant.checker.wxSpellCheckerDialog import wxSpellCheckerDialog
app = wx.App()
text = "This is sme text with a fw speling errors in it. Here are a fw more to tst it ut."
dlg = wxSpellCheckerDialog(None,-1,"")
chkr = SpellChecker("en_US",text)
dlg.SetSpellChecker(chkr)
dlg.ShowModal()
checked_text = dlg.error_text.GetValue()
print (checked_text)
dlg.Destroy()
app.MainLoop()
```

Sadly there appear to be a few bugs in the implementation. In that the whole text is not always returned. It appears to depend on resizing the window and/or how much of the text you have checked. Either that or my perfunctory look at it, missed something vital.
Use `print (dir(dlg))` to check what items are available.